# How to resolve the complexity of single table inheritance in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, rails-models

I'm currently refactoring my rails app. The tricky part so far is the table `posts`.

In the current version I'm using `posts` for:

- questions
- answers
- comments

*Using the `post_type` attribute.*

**Relationships:**

- Questions have many answers and comments.
- Answers have many comments.
- Answer belongs to a question.
- Comment belongs to either an answer or a question.

---

So far I was splitting the question and answer post types into seperate models, using the same table: `posts`. But with comments I have the following problem:

Every Post, but comments, is commentable. Would it be a good idea to create an additional `comments` table and create a polymorphic association 'commentable' to each of the post types instead of inheriting the posts table?

Comment: I think it makes sense to pull them out to 'commentable', since if you don't you would 'comments' in both the quesions and answers table (or you would be rejoinig the posts table for answer comments'. just seems cleaner.  this is assuming that a question comment and an answer comment have the same fields/requirements

Comment: Yes the comment structor is the same for every post type. I'm also thinking about splitting the entire posts table into questions and answers for easier maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then I started reading you question the first thing I thought was to first separate models (as a non- or less-destructible change) and then in a second step to separate db tables.

Concerning comments I think you should have a `Comment` model that is polymorphically associated with `Answer` and `Question`.

So in the first step you should separate current `Post` model into: `Question`, `Answer`, and `Comment`, but keep using posts db table (so I guess default_scope in each of these models setting proper post_type value)

Second step  would be (after first is tested, tested again and probably even deployed to crush test) to migrate data for each model into separate db table. That will make app design way easier, less data in a single table, etc. It shouldn't even have negative performance impact as sql query count will not change.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is what I will do. I was watching the RailsCasts to STI and Polymorphism and decided to remove the STI for better maintenance.